# How to show filtered legend labels in pyplot pie chart based on the values of contributions?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, pie-chart

I would like to plot a pie chart that shows contributions that are more than 1%, and their corresponding legend label.

I have managed showing the percentage values I wanted on the pie (see script below), but not the legend labels. In the following example, I want to show legend labels ABCD, but not EF.

I have tried several things, but only able to show either a full legend, or a filtered legend with unmatched (wrong) colors.

How can I do this? Can someone help? Thanks.

```
sizes = pd.DataFrame([80,10,5,4,0.1,0.9],index=list("ABCDEF"))

fig1, ax2 = plt.subplots()

def autopct_more_than_1(pct):
    return ('%1.f%%' % pct) if pct > 1 else ''

ax2.pie(sizes.values, autopct=autopct_more_than_1)
ax2.axis('equal') 

plt.legend(sizes.index, loc="best", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the dataframe values (possibly normalized if they aren't already) and only take the legend handles and labels for those which are bigger than 1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sizes = pd.DataFrame([80,10,5,4,0.1,0.9],index=list("ABCDEF"))

fig1, ax = plt.subplots()

def autopct_more_than_1(pct):
    return ('%1.f%%' % pct) if pct > 1 else ''

p,t,a = ax.pie(sizes.values, autopct=autopct_more_than_1)
ax.axis('equal') 

# normalize dataframe (not actually needed here, but for general case)
normsizes = sizes/sizes.sum()*100
# create handles and labels for legend, take only those where value is > 1
h,l = zip(*[(h,lab) for h,lab,i in zip(p,sizes.index.values,normsizes.values) if i > 1])

ax.legend(h, l,loc="best", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))

plt.show()
```

[image]